# How do I fill the email section using chrome driver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mluf.jpg)

Can you help me to input text on the email box? The email box appears when I click on `masuk` button on the top, but I can't get to `sendkeys` on the email box.

H|ere is the url- [www.tokopedia.com](https://www.tokopedia.com/)

And here is the code that does not work

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Download\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.tokopedia.com/");
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-accounts");
WebElement myEmail = driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail"));
myEmail.sendKeys("tes213");
WebElement myPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword"));
myPassword.sendKeys("tes123");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `does not work`? What is the result of your code executing?

Comment: it only click on the masuk button but wont click on the email box and wont fill it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because authorization form located inside `iframe` element. You need to switch to that frame at first and then handle input fields:

```
...
driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-accounts");
WebElement myEmail = driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail"));
myEmail.sendKeys("tes123");
...
```

To switch back you might need to use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

P.S. You don't need to click on input field to sent text to it, so `driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).click();` is redundant line

Comment: hi there your code works like double clicking on ifram-accounts so the iframe close immediatly

Comment: Are you sure that you don't use `driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link")).click();` two times in your code? You have to insert just one line `driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-accounts");` into your code

Comment: yes i didnt put driver.findElement(By.id("login-ddl-link")).click(); two times

Comment: I'm sure that switching to `iframe` couldn't close authorization form. Please use `edit` option to replace your code provided in question with updated one so I can see current version

Comment: here you go thank you very much for your help and i wonder if the google button, facebook button has an id?

Comment: You are clcking on `Masuk` two times: first time with `JavaScriptExecutor`, second- with common `click()` method... You should remove one of them (I advise you to remove `JavaScriptExecutor`)... I'm not sure that I understand what you mean `google button, facebook button`..

Comment: you are amazing thank you very much the google login button and facebook login button shows up on the iframe right below the password box but i dont know  how to click on that button because it doesnt have an id instead it has a href

Comment: You don't have to use `BY.id` only to locate web-element, you can also locate them by `Name`, `ClassName`, `XPath`... https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/05/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/. Check this also http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/real-browser-manual/building-a-testcase/how-locate-element-the-page/xpath-locator-examples/

Answer (score 0):

use this code it worked just fine for me on Chrome.

```
public static void main(String [] ar) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Download\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.tokopedia.com/");

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-ddl-link']"));

        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;           
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

        driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-accounts");

        WebElement myEmail = driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail"));
        myEmail.sendKeys("tes213");

        WebElement myPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword"));
        myPassword.sendKeys("tes123");

       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='global_login_btn']")).click();
 }
```